# AS3: A term is undefined when adding a shape inside a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip, addchild

I have what seems to be a very simple issue. I need to create a shape and add it inside a movie clip that is inside of another movie clip.

The code I am currently using is as follows:

```
var enemy_beacon:Shape = new Shape();
fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc.addChild(enemy_beacon);

fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc.enemy_beacon.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000, 1);
fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc.enemy_beacon.graphics.beginFill(0xFFBB00,1);                            
fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc.enemy_beacon.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 25);                                   
fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc.enemy_beacon.graphics.endFill();
```

However, this code throws an `Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.`

It seems to create the shape fine, but adding the shape (via addChild) or accessing any of its properties makes everything go haywire.

I already checked the instance names of the movie clips, everything is spelled correctly and nested correctly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Either `fullmenu_mc` or `menu_map_mc` are invalid references.

Comment: change `fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc.enemy_beacon.graphics` to `enemy_beacon.graphics`

Comment: Thanks everyone! Both answers worked... Andrey, I liked your solution since it gave me the ability to recall the children by name. Karolis and null.point, your solution didn't require naming and worked as well. I won't need to access the children beyond removing them, so that is perfect for my purpose. I'm a little confused why this works, though... Don't instances always need to be referred to through their parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `enemy_bacon` instance, you can access it directly:

```
var enemy_beacon:Shape = new Shape();
fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc.addChild(enemy_beacon);

enemy_beacon.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000, 1);
enemy_beacon.graphics.beginFill(0xFFBB00,1);                            
enemy_beacon.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 25);                                   
enemy_beacon.graphics.endFill();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't give a name to your Shape.

`fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc` doesn't know that your variable named `enemy_beacon` is the same that you've added to it's children.

Targeting children like that means that you are using their instance names. So `fullmenu_mc.menu_map_mc.enemy_beacon` means that you are searching a child called `enemy_beacon` inside `menu_map_mc`. And with the first two lines, you've just added **some** child to that menu item, but haven't specified name.

Instance names are not the same as your variables. Check this out:

```
var myShape:Shape = new Shape();
myShape.name = 'otherShape';
this.addChild(myShape); // you add specific item, name doesn't matter

trace (this.getChildByName('otherShape') == myShape); // you get child by NAME
// and because the child is the same as you've added, this will output: TRUE
```